# Remove email address from suggestions in To field on Gmail

Tags: gmail

Gmail keeps populating the **To** field with an out of date e-mail address that I no longer contact.

The email address isn't in my address book but I did use it a lot previously (the contact has since changed company and email address).

How do I tell Gmail to never show it to me again?

Comment: Most up-to-date answer: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131793/254855

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Delete their email address in [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com).

Comment: I have deleted the contact but when I go back to Gmail and type the first letter the name with the whole email address appear in the search box.

Comment: @dhaval Reload Gmail and search your contacts for the email address to make sure you really got rid of it.

Comment: google: a shortcut similar to the one use to delete a suggested url would be handy (ctrl+del)

Comment: In case anyone thinks they're going crazy, this doesn't ALWAYS work.  I have an email that is!not!in!my!contacts! and can not be made to go away.

Comment: There seems to be no such thing as "Gmail Contacts", so this answer might be outdated. There is "Google Contacts" https://contacts.google.com/?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, i've deleted an annoying contact, updated answer would be to navigate into contacts, using the 9 dot on the top right, delete the annoying contact. Gmail will now stop recommending them.

Answer (score 13):

Remember that **anyone you reply to in GMail gets a contact record created for them!**

To remove an unwanted autocomplete email address in GMail, remove the unwanted contact record.

- Select "contacts" from the drop-down menu at the top left.

  [image: GMail contacts menu]
- search for the unwanted contact in your address book by typing their name (or email, type it as you usually do in the to: field) in the search box

  [image: GMail contacts search]
- open the contact, then use the "more" menu at the top middle to select **delete**.

  [image: GMail delete contact]

Once the contact is deleted, the autocomplete in the to: field for that contact name/email will no longer occur.

(sorry Blake Edwards, you were merely the example! No offense intended!)

Comment: As of March 2018, this no longer works in all cases.

Comment: worked April 2019, did refresh GMail page after making changes. In what circumstance did it not work?

Answer (score 11):

Go to Contacts then search for the email address, select it, and delete it. It is probably under "All Contacts" and pops up because you used it frequently in the past.

Answer (score 11):

As of July 2019, Google must have changed the setup, making outdated the other answers given.

What works right now is deleting the address in [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/?hl=en).

Simply searching your contacts may not be sufficient - but you can begin typing the email in the Search field and when it shows up, click on it. That will bring up a Contacts "card" for that email, even if it is not a full contact that you have created. Select the three vertical dots at the top right, and Delete is one of the options.