# How to delete non-existant alias for ALL users in a G-suite?

Tags: google-contacts, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I'm the admin of G-Suite.

My (50) users see an unwanted contact (of a deleted alias) in their gmail to/cc/bcc auto-complete list.

How can I force removal of that "ghost" contact for **ALL users in my team at once?**

All answers I found so far put the responsibility on the end-user, e.g.: [Remove email address from suggestions in To field on Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18021/remove-email-address-from-suggestions-in-to-field-on-gmail)

I don't my users to do admin tasks, and besides, such situation happens every few months.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a contact in the user own "Other Contacts" list is not an "admin task". Anyway, if you want to do some tasks on behalf the your organization users, you could do them by using Google Apps Script (some tasks will require to use advanced services), you could use the corresponding API and use domain-wide delegation of authority or one of the command-line tools for G Suite administrators like [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM).

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/
- https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Related Questions

- [How to use the Gmail API, OAuth2 for Apps Script, and Domain-Wide Delegation to set email signatures for users in a G Suite domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40936257/1595451)

Comment: if i need to apply it to 50 users, it's an admin task; same as, ehmm, setting global signature.  The fault is google's - who didn't remove that alias from autocomplete as they do with deleted user.