# How to prevent email addresses from being suggested to "Add" when composing group emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-auto-complete

When composing an email to certain addresses in Gmail, it suggests more addresses to add. How can I prevent a specific email address from being suggested?

[image: Gmail suggesting email address with text]

I can remove the offending email address from all contacts (including "other contacts") and this will prevent the "person" being *suggested*. However, it will still suggest the "email address" only (from a "non-contact" - when hovering over this email address there is the option to "Add to contacts") - presumably because there are past emails where this email address is included. (I don't want to delete these emails.)

This Google Community thread from 2019/20 is asking the same question, without a solution:

- https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4904445/how-to-disable-suggested-email-recipients?hl=en

---

Failing that, how can I prevent Gmail from suggesting any emails to "Add" to the recipient list.

I've tried toggling the following "smart" features in Gmail "general" settings, but none seem to affect this "Add email suggestion" feature:

- Smart Compose / Writing suggestions
- Smart Compose personalisation
- Nudges: Suggest emails to reply to
- Smart Reply

---

**UPDATE:** To be clear, this is not related to the "auto-complete" email addresses in the "To", "Cc" and "Bcc" fields as discussed in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18021/remove-email-address-from-suggestions-in-to-field-on-gmail). That is relatively trivial to block (in 2023) by simply deleting the contact (or the email address for that contact).

What I'm asking about here is the feature where Gmail suggests additional recipients to "Add" when composing a group email. Nothing is "typed" or auto-completed.

The email address that is suggested to "Add" to the email does not necessarily exist in your contacts, it appears to be determined purely from past email interactions. Sometimes more than one email (or contact) is suggested in the "Add" line.

Another issue with this "Add" feature is that since it is determined from (dim and distant) *past* emails, it can suggest "old" (out of date) email addresses to "Add" when you might already have updated that contact's new email address within your Google Contacts!

Comment: While over the years, Google has been adding more features to Gmail; we should not forget that it is a "light weight" email client about the customization options offered by Google. On the other hand, the Gmail web application user interface features can be "easily" hidden by using HTML/CSS/JavaScript. This code could be handled using web browser features like bookmarks / favorites, "developers tools" and web browser extensions like AdBlock, Stylebot, TamperMonkey, among others. Are you open to using HTML/JavaScript/CSS? If so, please show what you have tried in this regard.

Comment: @Rubén Although Gmail is probably the worlds most popular email client and used by many businesses. This "issue" doesn't only affect the web interface, but also the Gmail apps on both Android and iOS. This is affecting multiple users where installing a script/plugin is not an option.

Comment: Overall, questions are OK, but not always for the general public to craft a solution that works across all platforms. If you are looking for Google to change the platform, you should submit your request directly to Google, if you are looking open to having different solutions according to the possibilities each platform allows to the general public, you should consider posting multiple questions, i.e. [android.se] and [apple.se] for the Play Store and the App Store apps respectively. Please [edit] the question to clarify the scope of the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Please bear in mind that requests to Internet service vendors like Google / Gmail to change their platform are off-topic. Such requests should be addressed to the developer / operator through the respective customer service channels.